# Deploy Sencha/ JQuery Mobile as one touch launched app in Android / IPhone

Tags: iphone, android, extjs, jquery-mobile

I was wondering by using [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) or [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/), is it possible

1. Is it possible to deploy them as single click install app in Android Market?
2. Is it possible to deploy them as single click install app in IPhone App Store? Does Apple place any restriction on non-native app deploy through IPhone App Store?
3. How can I package my HTML, JS and CSS files as one click executable file? That's is, by single click on the icon on mobile "desktop", browser will launch a default HTML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, yes, yes.  PhoneGap and Appcelerator Titanium are two frameworks that enable all three.

Answer (score 1):

Sencha touch will be the best option for application because its has the support for phone gap to build your application for other mobile platforms and it has large community that help when are stack and its famework is well documented